# Пайтон. Задание на последовательность

Tags: python, python-3.x

В пайтоне новичок, помогите как можно это реализовать?

Дана последовательность из 100 целых чисел,возможные повторения. Определить количество чисел в самой долгой последовательности из нулей, которые идут подряд (в серии нулей). Результат вывести на экран.

Comment: покажите что вы пробовали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На будущее: в сообществе StackOverflow принято показывать своё решение, чтобы другие могли указать на ваши ошибки и исправить их, а не решать задачу за вас.

Решение вашей задачи:

```py
from random import randint

# вместо 0, 5 указываем диапазон, в котором генерируются целые числа. Например, целые числа могут быть от -4 до 42. У меня от 0 до 5, чтобы длиннее были последовательности
a = [randint(0, 5) for _ in range(100)]
longest = 0
now = 0

for elem in a:
  if elem == 0:
    now += 1
  elif now > longest:
    longest = now
    now = 0
  else:
    now = 0
  
print('Последовательность:', a)
print('Самая большая серия нулей:', longest)
```

Результат:

```py
Последовательность: [5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 0, 3, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 2, 0, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 0, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 4,2, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 0, 4, 2, 2]
Самая большая серия нулей: 3
```